# Error: expected a string or a class/function but got: undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am having the error **Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined in my resolverSections component. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports. resolveSections component.** This component is responsible for generating the sections that come from my data. But I have the problem that locally if the test passes but in my github workflow it fails.
the error is the following:

```
FAIL src/app/template/resolverSections.spec.tsx (5.855 s)
```

● resolverSections › should render Main section correctly

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `Dependents`.

  68 |       }
  69 |
> 70 |     render(MainSection as React.ReactElement);
     |           ^
  71 |
  72 |     const tabLabels = screen.getAllByRole('tab');
  73 |     const tabContents = screen.getAllByTestId('tab-content');

  at createFiberFromTypeAndProps (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:28439:17)
  at createFiberFromElement (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:28465:15)
  at createChild (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:15109:28)
  at reconcileChildrenArray (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:15404:25)
  at reconcileChildFibers (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:15821:16)
  at reconcileChildren (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:19167:28)
  at updateHostComponent (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:19924:3)
  at beginWork (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21618:14)
  at beginWork$1 (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:27426:14)
  at performUnitOfWork (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:26560:12)
  at workLoopSync (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:26466:5)
  at renderRootSync (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:26434:7)
  at recoverFromConcurrentError (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:25850:20)
  at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:25750:22)
  at flushActQueue (node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:2667:24)
  at act (node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:2582:11)
  at node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/act-compat.js:46:25
  at renderRoot (node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/pure.js:161:26)
  at render (node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/pure.js:247:10)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/app/template/resolverSections.spec.tsx:70:11)
```

I have reviewed the types, the test data but I have not found the source of the problem.
I share part of the code.

**ResolverSections.tsx**

```
import { resolverComponent } from "./resolverComponent"
import { ScheduleSectionC, ContactInformation, Dependents, RequiredDocuments, ItemizedDeductions, EstimatedTaxPayments, ScheduleSectionE } from "../modules";
import { Box } from "@mui/material";
import { SectionsType, IResolverProps, ISection, ComponentType } from "../models";


export const resolverSections: {
  [key in SectionsType]?: (props: IResolverProps) => React.ReactNode;
} = {
  [SectionsType.Main]: (props) => {
    const { activeTab, setActiveTab, sections, attributes } = props;

    return (
      <>
        {resolverComponent[ComponentType.Tabs]({
          activeTab,
          setActiveTab,
          attributes,
          ...props,
        })}
        {sections &&
          sections?.length &&
          sections.map((subSections: ISection, index: number) =>
            resolverComponent[ComponentType.Tab]({ section: subSections, index, value: activeTab })
          )}
      </>
    );
  },
  [SectionsType.Section1040]: (props) => {
    const { sections } = props?.section || { name: '', sections: [] };
    return <Box key={`${SectionsType.Section1040}-0`} data-testid={'1040-section'}>
      {sections && (sections as ISection[]).map((section: ISection) => resolverSections[section?.name as SectionsType]?.({
        ...section,
        name: SectionsType.Section1040
      }))}
    </Box>
  },
  [SectionsType.ScheduleC]: (props) => {
    const { sections } = props?.section || { name: '', sections: [] };
    if (!sections) return;

    return <Box key={`${SectionsType.ScheduleC}-1`}>
      <ScheduleSectionC sections={sections as ISection[]} name={SectionsType.Business} index={2} />
    </Box>
  },
  [SectionsType.ScheduleE]: (props) => {
    const { sections } = props?.section || { name: '', sections: [] };

    return <Box key={`${SectionsType.ScheduleE}-2`}>
      <ScheduleSectionE sections={sections as ISection[]} name={SectionsType.Property} index={1} />
    </Box >
  },
  [SectionsType.ContactInformation]: (props) => {
    const { sections, index } = props;
    return <ContactInformation sections={sections} index={index} />
  },
  [SectionsType.Dependents]: (props) => {
    const { sections } = props;

    return <Dependents sections={sections} index={props.index} />
  },
  [SectionsType.RequiredDocuments]: (props) => {
    const { sections, index } = props;
    return <RequiredDocuments sections={sections} index={index} />
  },
  [SectionsType.ItemizedDeductions]: (props) => {
    const { sections } = props;
    return <ItemizedDeductions sections={sections} index={props?.index} />
  },
  [SectionsType.EstimatedTaxPayments]: (props) => {
    const { sections } = props;

    return <EstimatedTaxPayments sections={sections} index={props.index} />
  },
}
```

**resolverSections.spec.tsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import { resolverSections } from './resolverSections';
import { SectionsType } from '../models';

describe('resolverSections', () => {
  it('should render Main section correctly', async () => {
    const mockProps = {
        sections: [
            {
                name: SectionsType.Section1040,
                sections: [
                    {
                        name: SectionsType.ContactInformation,
                        sections: [
                            {
                                name: "contacts",
                                sections: []
                            },
                            {
                                mailingAddress: ""
                            },
                            {
                                routingNumber: ""
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        name: SectionsType.Dependents,
                        sections: []
                    },
                    {
                        name: SectionsType.EstimatedTaxPayments,
                        sections: []
                    },
                    {
                        name: SectionsType.RequiredDocuments,
                        sections: []
                    },
                    {
                        name: SectionsType.ItemizedDeductions,
                        sections: []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                name: SectionsType.ScheduleE,
                sections: []
            },
            {
                name: SectionsType.ScheduleC,
                sections: []
            }
        ],
        activeTab: 0,
        name: SectionsType.Main,
        attributes: {
            scheduleE: 2,
            scheduleC: 1
        }
    }
    let MainSection: React.ReactNode;
    if (resolverSections[SectionsType.Main]) {
      MainSection = resolverSections[SectionsType.Main](mockProps);
    } else {
        MainSection = <div>No MainSection</div>;
      }

    render(MainSection as React.ReactElement);

    const tabLabels = screen.getAllByRole('tab');
    const tabContents = screen.getAllByTestId('tab-content');
    expect(tabLabels).toHaveLength(3);
    expect(tabLabels[0]).toHaveTextContent('1040');
    expect(tabContents).toHaveLength(3);
  });

  it('should render Section 1040 correctly', () => {
    const mockProps = {
        "name": SectionsType.Section1040,
        "sections": [
            {
               "name": "",
               sections: [],
            }
        ]
      };
      let Section1040: React.ReactNode;
      if (resolverSections[SectionsType.Section1040]) {
        Section1040 = resolverSections[SectionsType.Section1040](mockProps);
      } else {
        Section1040 = <div>No Section1040</div>;
      }
  
      render(Section1040 as React.ReactElement);

    const subSections = screen.getAllByTestId('1040-section');
    expect(subSections).toHaveLength(1);
  });
});
```

**In my modules folder I have the index.ts file with the exports of each module.**

```
export * from './Business/Business';
export * from './ContactInformation/ContactInformation';
export * from './Dependents/Dependents';
export * from './EstimatedTaxPayments/EstimatedTaxPayments';
export * from './Home/Home';
export * from './ItemizedDeductions/ItemizedDeductions';
export * from './Property/Property';
export * from './RequiredDocuments/RequiredDocuments';
export * from './ScheduleSectionC/ScheduleSectionC';
export * from './Home/Home';
export * from './EvidencesViewer/EvidencesViewer';
export * from './ScheduleSectionE/ScheduleSectionE';
export * from './PunchListProgressBar/PunchListProgressBar';
```